# No implicits found for parameters i0: TypedColumn.Exists

Tags: scala, apache-spark, frameless

I am trying out frameless library for Scala and getting an "No implicits found for parameters i0: TypedColumn.Exists". If you can help me resolve it - that would be awesome....

I am using spark 2.4.0 and frameless 0.8.0.

Following is my code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import frameless.TypedDataset

object TestSpark {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("Spark Test")
      .getOrCreate

    import spark.implicits._

    val empDS = spark.read
      .option("header",true)
      .option("delimiter",",")
      .csv("emp.csv")
      .as[Emp]

    val empTyDS = TypedDataset.create(empDS)
    import frameless.syntax._

    empTyDS.show(10,false).run

    val deptCol = empTyDS('dept) //Get the error here.`
  }
}
```

case class for the code is

```
case class Emp (
  name: String,
  dept: String,
  manager: String,
  salary: String
)
```

Comment: If you're using IntelliJ, it must be an IDE error. Try to compile anyway.

Comment: Thanks - It worked! - still some teething issues with frameless.